# angularjs hide vertical scrollbar for mobile devices

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an application using bootstrap and angular js.

I have a left side dynamic navigation bar containing more data.(customer numbers)

my requirement is, initially don't want to show the scroll bar for mobile devices. it should visible the scroll bar only when scrolling.

How do i achieve this functionality with angular?

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li class="sidebar-brand">
              <a href>
                  Customer view
              </a>
          </li>
          <li ng-repeat="customer in customerData" ng-class="{activeBlock: $index == selected}">
              <a href data-toggle="tab">{{customer.CustomerNumber}}</a>
          </li>          
      </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
```

Comment: do you really need to use angular? you can implement it using poor css, just add media query where you check screen width and add overflow-y - hidden

Comment: use ionic framework. it is amazing using angularjs and perfect for mobile. hybrid mobile app